# JQueryUI AutoComplete w/ Multi-Select - Remove Selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, multi-select

I'm using the JQuery Auto-Complete widget, with multi-select, as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z26yv/.

Here's the code:

```
<label>Teams:</label>
<input type="text" id="teams" />
<br />
<br />
<label>Team IDs:</label>
<input id="team_ids" />

$(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            {label: "Choice1", value: "Choice1", db: 1},
            {label: "Choice2", value: "Choice2", db: 2},
            {label: "Choice3", value: "Choice3", db: 3},
            {label: "Choice4", value: "Choice4", db: 4},
            {label: "Choice5", value: "Choice5", db: 5},
            {label: "Choice6", value: "Choice6", db: 6},
            {label: "different text", value: "different text", db: 7},
        ];

        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }

        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }

        $("#teams")
        //don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
                //delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
            },
            focus: function() {
                //prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                //remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                //add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                //add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");

                $('#team_ids').val($('#team_ids').val() + "," + ui.item.db);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

The idea is that a user will make one or more selections, and each time the ID for the selected item will be added to a (hidden) field. The issue I'm running in to is what happens if they remove a selection? Since it's a text box, the user can just go in an backspace/delete a team, and there doesn't appear to be an event in the auto-complete that will capture this. The JQueryUI auto-complete API is here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Perhaps I need to utilize the change event, and somehow pull out the IDs for the currently-selected values? I'm not entirely sure how to go about that.

Also, any thoughts on removing selected options from the search? I'm thinking I'd have to remove a selected option from the availableTags array, and then add it back if it it was un-selected.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A plugin like select2 might suit your needs a bit better, as much as I love jQueryUI autocomplete

Comment: That looks like an awesome plugin @AndrewWhitaker. Unfortunately there's some resistance to installing new 3rd party code, and we already make use of JQueryUI in other areas. I'll take a look and see if I can make a case for it though!

Comment: I totally understand. Two questions that might make this easier: Are you constraining input to what's in the available tags array? Is deleting a whole word when the user hits backspace acceptable?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - Yes and yes. Teams are defined in another area, and this is where a user is associated with one or more teams.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - Okay I've taken a look at Select2, and I'm going to do everything I can to get the bosses to accept it. It's perfect for our needs, and is so quick and clean. I could spend ages trying to figure out how to do this in JQueryUI, or about 5 mins setting it up in Select2. Thanks so much!